# How to adjust PlotLabel

Tags: plotting

I make the PlotLabel for my plot by

```
label = {" Y1 =  4 , Y3 > 4  , Y3 < Y1 Y2 , Y3+ Y4 - |Y5| > 5 "};
color = {Blue};
legend = Row[Style[##, 30] & @@@ Transpose[{label, color}], Spacer[20]];

Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, PlotLabel -> legend, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False]
```

This yields a row of label up the graph. How to adjust `legend` in my command to get two  columns of the labels instead of a row  ?

i.e., I want to get up the graph:

`Y1 =  4 ,       Y3 > 4,`

`Y3 < Y1 Y2,     Y3+ Y4 - |Y5| > 5`

**Edit**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
label = {"Y1 =  4,", "Y3 > 4", 
   "Y3 < Y1 Y2,", "Y3+ Y4 - |Y5| > 5"};
legend = Grid[
   Partition[Style[##, Blue, 30] & /@ label, 2],
   Alignment -> Left];

Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, PlotLabel -> legend, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  For multiple colors (I use `Red` vice `Black` since it is difficult for me to distinguish between `Blue` and `Black`).

```
colors = {Blue, Red};
n = 0;
legend = Grid[
   Partition[Style[#, colors[[Mod[n++, Length[colors]] + 1]], 30] & /@ label, 
    2],
   Alignment -> Left];

Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, PlotLabel -> legend, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Or perhaps you want something like,

```
Column[{legend,
  Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False]}]
```

[image]

Comment: What if I have two colors, e.x. :     `label = {"Y1 =  4,", "Y3 > 4", "Y3 < Y1 Y2,", "Y3+ Y4 - |Y5| > 5", "label2"};`  and `colors ={Blue, Black};`

Comment: ****  Thanks ****

Comment: Hay @Bob Hanlon,  for the labels alignment up the graph, I used in legend : `legend = Grid[
   Partition[
    Style[#, colors[[Mod[n++, Length[colors]] + 1]], 30] & /@ label, 
    2], Alignment -> {{-1, 1} -> Left}];` and it gave me as the attached edited figure in the question, all the labels mostly centered. How to bring all the labels to the left edge of the graph ?

Comment: @S.S. - I don't understand what you are trying to do but look at second edit.

Comment: It's ok @Bob Hanlon, that's just bring the label to left edge ..